# Set as `NA` when Arrow's schema cannot parse values of a CSV in R

Tags: r, csv, parsing, apache-arrow

I am trying to read a `csv` (~ 18,000,000 rows, ~ 1000 columns) into arrow (in `R`) with `open_dataset` pre-specifying a `schema`. There are some instances in which the `csv` was generated incorrectly and some values don't match the intended schema (say some values where the `age` (`int`) of the individual was supposed to be entered have the `name` (`string`) of the individual). My intention is to set these ages that have strings that can't be parsed as integers as `NA`.

The default behaviour of `open_dataset` is to throw the following error:

```
 CSV conversion error to int8: invalid value
```

> Is there a way in which instead of getting an error when the schema is unable to parse I can get a missing value `NA`?

Here is an example of code that generates the error:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)

#Write csv 
tibble(age = c(1,2,"StackOverflow",5)) %>%
  write_csv("example.csv")

#Read the csv
arrow::open_dataset("example.csv", format = "csv", schema = schema(age = int8()), skip = 1) %>% 
  collect()
```

I know that I can specify the `null_values` inside the `CsvConvertOptions` if I know them *previously* as follows:

```
arrow::open_dataset("example.csv",  format = "csv", schema = schema(age = int8()), skip = 1,
     convert_options = CsvConvertOptions$create(null_values = "StackOverflow")) %>% 
     collect()
```

However this feels pretty inefficient as not knowing the mistakes *a priori* it seems to me that I need to go through the data twice (once to search the values and then once to set the schema correctly).

Comment: RodrigoZepeda, I don't know if this is possible (I'm still learning arrow/parquet), but if it isn't, this is such a fundamental base function that should be present, would you be willing to write a [feature-request](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+csv+default+value)? I feel it would be of high value to many. In the interim, have you tried using `mutate(n = cast(n as int8()))` (or similar), as suggested [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/12469#issuecomment-1046246626)?